# There is no problem in considering bump functions in complex space, is there?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to use that a given set $\mathscr{F}$ of continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is trivially nowhere vanishing, that is for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I can always find $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in this set such that $g(x) \not=0$. This set $\mathscr{F}$ has the property that each element $f \in \mathscr{F}$ vanishes at infinity (the set $\lbrace x \hspace{1pt}| \hspace{2pt} |f(x)| < \varepsilon \rbrace$ is compact) a easy argument for this would be to consider a bump function centered at any given point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But this would imply that one can talk about bump functions that map to the complex numbers, I do know that by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions any analytic function that is zero in a interval must be zero everywhere and that by Liouville's theorem every bounded entire function must be bounded.

But those talk about, analytic / holomorphic / entire functions, not about arbitrary continuous functions, so is there any problem in considering bump functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$? Since I can't seem to find those being used in complex analysis.

Comment: As you already pointed out, bump functions have no business in the study of holomorphic functions. They do show up in several complex variables and complex geometry in relating holomorphic things to smooth things.

Comment: There's nothing illogical about such functions. You can view $\Bbb C$ as just $\Bbb R^2$ (ignoring its multiplicative structure and keeping just the vector space or topological structure). Your first paragraph is confusing, though. Are you trying to find a family $\mathscr F$ with given properties?

Comment: Are you thinking in something like $\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\displaystyle{-\frac{1-2|z|}{|z|^4+|z|^2(1-2|z|)}}\right)},\quad |z|<1$?

Comment: Actually I am just trying to prove that if $f$ is a bounded continuous function then $f$ is strongly continuous. The proof depends on the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that for complex valued functions, and that needs the hypothesis that the subalgebra of functions considered (in this case $S_0 = S \cap C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, where $S$ is the set of  strongly continuous functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$) is nowhere vanishing (for the locally Hausdorff version of the theorem).